# How to find examples of "mobile (usecases, user-stories, flowcharts, etc)"

Tags: mobile

My experience has been that paper prototypes are the fastest way to get mobile apps built.

That said, I'm interested in getting more exposure to the thought process other UX professionals went through at a high-level to define the flow of an app.

As a result, I'm looking for suggestions on how to find professional grade examples of:

- mobile usecases,
- mobile user-stories,
- mobile flowcharts,
- etc.

While not amazing visually, here's one example of what this might mean, but please do not read to much into it as an example other than it might provide some proof that I've already done some research on the subject: [Mobile Device APIs Use Cases](http://www.openajax.org/member/wiki/Mobile_Device_APIs_Use_Cases).

Comment: @vote-to-close: Please explain why you believe the question is "not constructive", thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a couple of useful articles from Feb 2011 on the design decisions and thought processes that went into [Basecamp Mobile](http://basecamp.com/mobile), written by Jason Zimdars.

- [Design Decisions: Basecamp mobile UI](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2778-design-decisions-basecamp-mobile-ui)
- [Providing great user experience with feedback](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2771-providing-great-user-experience-with-feedback)

Luke Wroblewski provides a summary of [Mobile use cases](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?922) - namely Check In, Entertainment, Communication, Local, Look Up, Utilities and also covers many aspects of user behaviour in his book Mobile First.

Smashing magazine did a nice article in July 2011 - [Seven Guidelines For Designing High-Performance Mobile User Experiences](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/18/seven-guidelines-for-designing-high-performance-mobile-user-experiences/) which touches on user stories, flows and elements, but more importantly covers other topics which all need to be considered.

Possibly of use: *Compete* did [a survey](http://blog.compete.com/2010/03/12/smartphone-owners-a-ready-and-willing-audience/) on how much time is spent on their smartphone at various times of the day.

It can be useful to generate personas and user stories but also, really consider using *customer journey maps* as well: [eg these examples on Google images](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=customer%20journey%20map&hl=en&newwindow=1&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=LJyaT4zbMIj54QSXvbX1Dg&ved=0CFEQsAQ&biw=1920&bih=952)